# PHP code updates all the rows in my mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

i'm working on a school project where you need to be able to update rows in the mysql database. i've got this working, but when clicking update, it updates ALL the rows and not only one. This is the code i'm trying to use:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE posts
        SET post_header='$tittel', post_author='$author', post_content='$content'
        WHERE idpost_posts='$proitem'") or die (mysql_error());
```

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by `..it updates ALL the rows and not only one`? All rows in the table or all rows that matches the condition `idpost_posts='$proitem'`?

Comment: check your condition in where clause it must be matching with more than one record set.

Comment: I need it to update one row which has the same id as given, you can see in the code. By that i mean it updates all the rows, even if the id number dosent match

Comment: it isn matchin with more than one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very big chance you are having a wrong where condition.
Echo your query to see which query is executed to check which value is passed in your where condition.
Everything provided in the where condition will be updated so if the value maches more rows, these rows are all updated which is normal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The value for `$proitem` must be unique to 1 row.